# Is there a way of disabling nosleep.js at setup in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

A-Frame makes use of nosleep.js to keep phones from sleeping (it plays a small video file in the background). For my use case, I need A-Frame to *not* activate nosleep.js.

I can disable nosleep.js by modifying the aframe.js file itself (search for "USE_WAKELOCK" and hardcode to false), but I'd prefer to do it programmatically in setup if possible. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wakelock object is created as a `<a-scene>` property ([source code](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.9.0/src/core/scene/wakelock.js)). [Here](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v0.9.0/vendor/wakelock/wakelock.js) you can check out the implementation.

When entering VR mode it's executing `wakelock.request()`, and upon exiting - `wakelock.release()`.
Having a reference to the scene, you can call those methods:

```
var scene = document.querySelector("a-scene")
// scene.wakelock.release() / scene.wakelock.request()
```

I'd disable it, by listening for the `enter-vr` event, and releasing the wakelock after a couple ms delay.

```
scene.addEventListener('enter-vr', function () { 
    setTimeout(e => {wakelock.release();}, 100) 
});
```

---

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Law5kesq/1/) with the object logged. It will be created only when mobile is detected, you can select the device toolbar (chrome) / Responsive Design Mode (ff)

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, thank you so much. My first time asking a question on a forum and I haven't been disappointed!

Comment: @DanteP.Fayre glad i could help, have fun :)